# cleantext module can not be imported on google colab pro

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, python-import

In google colab, I could install and import clean-text module well, but after changing the account to google colab pro, this module can not be imported. I've tried these lines of code for installing:

```
!pip install -q clean-text[gpl]
```

and

```
!conda install clean-text[gpl]
```

and

```
!pip install cleantext
```

and I imported it like this:

```
import cleantext
```

or

```
from cleantext import clean
```

but I got this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cleantext'

How can I fix this on google colab pro?

Answer (score 0):

If it is not importing directly from pip then, You can use google drive to import the library.
First connect drive to colab.
second upload library source files in the drive.
third import library in colab notebook.

Comment: Maybe you could point in the direction of how to do this?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Install this module in this way:

```
!pip install clean_text
```